# Cannot aireplay-ng deauth attack Android 11

Tags: wifi, android, deauth-attack

I was trying to do a deauth attack on Android 11 phone but it didn't work. I am using

`sudo aireplay-ng --deauth 100000 -a [AP mac_addr] -c [my mac_addr] wlan0`

The access point uses wpa2 encryption, channel is 9, it only supports 2.4ghz.

I am sending those deauth packets to an Android 11 phone.

There were no errors while running the deauth command or while changing my wifi adapter to monitor mode or any errors in general. It is a fresh install of kali.

I am able to deauth my Samsung Tyzen TV and my other Android 8 mobile. I am unable to do it only in my main mobile device

Comment: Does the Android disconnect from the AP at all?

Comment: Welcome to the community. You of course have promiscous mode enabled, right?

Comment: @scheoder it does

Comment: @Sir Muffington what is that?

Comment: @scheoder it does disconnect from my android 8 device but not on my android 11 device

Comment: It's a mode in your driver required for your use case if I recall correctly.